# Scala how to unit test object extends App trait

Tags: scala

I have a Scala object which extends `App` trait.

For example

```
object Main extends App {
  args.length match {
     case 0 => ???
     case 1 => ???
     case _ => ???
  }
}
```

How can I unit test this object?

Comment: Why not just call the `main` method from inside a unit test?

Comment: @Madoc because it would block the further execution of test, which prevents from testing services?

Comment: @Worse_Username How so? Other tests would run fine after it.

Comment: @Madoc, you would execute main() method of the App, but the rest of the test would not execute because the App is stuck in endless loop.

Comment: @Worse_Username That could happen with any other method too. Usually, programs have some kind of exit option, which should also be tested. My point was: When testing, trait the main method like any other method that you would test. Because it is. I did it like this with good success.